# Keyboard layout pico

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

I am working on a project to make a badusb out of an raspberry pi pico but i have some problems, when the payload executes,it opens my file explorer and i want it to be a HID device so how do i do that? (in the boot.py?), and when it starts typing it starts typing gibberish (see image below)
Does anyone know how to fix this?
[Gibberish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJHLH.jpg)
I'm using the NLD - INTL keyboard layout

I tried using different layout mpy files but there wasnt one for NLD - INTL or something simular
This is my circuitpy and the layouts
[CIRCUITPY - LIB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrFdu.png)
[FILES IN ADAFRUIT_HID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjC54.png)

Answer (score 0):

A keyboard does not really know anything about characters. It just sends "scancodes", i.e. an identifier which key is pressed or released. This can be a single byte, but often there are multiple bytes sent.
The translation from scancode to character is done in the keyboard driver on the PC side, where the keyboard layout is used to find the character for the scancode.

Your screenshot shows that the letter "q" is output when you want to send "a" instead. I presume you use something like

```
kbd.press(Keycode.A)
```

This only works if the reverse operation (convert keycode to scancode) is available. So you need the .NL just to get that. But you can enter the correct scancode directly. As [https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html) suggests this should be a 0x10 for the character "Q".

So try

```
kbd.press(0x10)
```

instead, maybe that helps.